# Is there a way to select from a list of subnets where to launch an EC2 instance in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to do a CF template to spin up three different environments but I want to be able to select in which subnet the EC2 instance is launched without hardcoding a specific subnet in the template. In my example below however I get an error that SubnetId must be a string. I can't think of any other way to achieve this. Any thoughts?

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentType:
    Type: String
    Default: Dev  
    AllowedValues:
      - Dev  
      - Test 
      - Production
    Description: Select Environment Type (Dev, Test, Production)
  SubnetIdList:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: 
      - Public1
      - Public2
      - Private
    Description: Select a subnet
  
    

Mappings:
  InstanceSize:
    Dev:
      "EC2" : "t3.micro"
    Test:
      "EC2" : "t3.small"
    Production:
      "EC2" : "t3.medium"
  Sub:
    Public1:
      "Subnet" : "subnet-05daa558dc3f65529" #public 1
    Public2:
      "Subnet" : "subnet-0f57bb83e0fc545f4" #public 2
    Private:
      "Subnet" : "subnet-0eb76c49954acc803" #Private
    
    
    

Resources:
  EC2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0080e4c5bc078760e
      InstanceType: !FindInMap [InstanceSize, !Ref EnvironmentType, EC2]
      KeyName: Ashkelon
      SubnetId: [Sub, !Ref SubnetIdList, Subnet]
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Are you merely wanting the `Subnet` parameter to list existing subnets? If so, you could change the parameter to use a Type of `AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id`. This will list all available subnets. See also: [CloudFormation Template (JSON) for EC2 with VPC, Subnet & Security Group Choices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56569604/174777)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing `!FindInMap` in your Ec2 subnet parameter definition. See below

```
Resources:
  EC2:
     Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
     Properties:
     ImageId: ami-0080e4c5bc078760e
     InstanceType: !FindInMap [InstanceSize, !Ref EnvironmentType, EC2]
     KeyName: Ashkelon
     SubnetId: !FindInMap [Sub, !Ref SubnetIdList, Subnet]
```